# Finding an explicit expression for a recurrence relation from the generating function

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

So I have the recurrence relation $c_n = 3 c_{n-1} - c_{n-2}$ and have calculated its generating function to be $F(z) = \frac{1}{1-3z+z^2}$.

I now need to find an explicit expression for $c_n$, but I'm really not sure how to do this, if someone could help me out that would be great.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation This link may help.

Comment: Hint: Factorise the denominator of $F(z)$ into the form $(1-r_1z)(1-r_2z)$ where $r_1r_2=1$ and $r_1+r_2=3$. Determine $r_1$ and $r_2$ then separate $F(z)$ into partial fractions. Hopefully you can see what to do from there.

Answer (score 2):

With a bit of experience one may recognize in $x^2-3x+1$ the minimal polynomial of $\varphi^2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, where $\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is the golden ratio. This is enough to be able to state that $[z^n]\frac{1}{1-3z+z^2}$ only depends on $F_{2n}$ and $F_{2n+2}$. Actually

$$ \sum_{n\geq 0} F_n z^n = \frac{z}{1-z-z^2} $$
implies
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0} F_{2n} z^{2n} = \frac{1}{2}\left[ \frac{z}{1-z-z^2}+ \frac{-z}{1+z-z^2}\right] = \frac{z^2}{1-3z^2+z^4}$$
and
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0} F_{2n}\,z^{n} = \frac{z}{1-3z+z^2}$$
so
$$ \frac{1}{1-3z+z^2} = \sum_{n\geq 0}\color{red}{F_{2n+2}}\,z^n.$$